# php if checkbox checked <select> list appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the follow problem guys, i have create a simple page with a ckeckbox, and i want when the checkbox is checked a  (list) appearing and if not checked list2 appearing,without using sumbit

```
<body>
    <input type="checkbox1" name="ckeck">
    <?php if checkbox1 is ckecked { ?>
    <select name="list" size="1">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
    </select>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <select name="list2" size="1">
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="25">25</option>
    </select>
    <?php } ?>
</body>
```

I hope the code help more....

Comment: Please take the time to format your code correctly. It makes it much quicker for others to read and help you with.

Comment: what you are trying is not possible with PHP. look for javascipt solutions.

Comment: @Aris, nothing impossible, we can to reload a page when checkbox clicked :)

Comment: @vp_arth i don't think the OP wants to refresh the page. and how you plan to keep it checked after reload?

Comment: @Aris, just render it already checked: `<?php echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP does not have access to the DOM; you'll need JavaScript for that. If you must use PHP to react to a checkbox, then you'll want to look into using AJAX. Basically you'll use JavaScript (ideally jQuery) to react to the immediate checkbox event, which will use AJAX to communicate with your PHP script. Your PHP script will return some sort of data. The data could be JSON containing the list data (I recommend this one), could be raw JavaScript code to be executed, or it could simply return a boolean that determines whether the list will display or not. Those are just some ideas.

If it's not a security issue, you could just move all the PHP logic to the client-side and do *everything* in JavaScript. You'll probably have a better user experience and there's potential for less server strain.

**tl;dr**: Use JS instead. Otherwise use JS to handle checkbox events, AJAX against PHP script, PHP generates data, JS interprets result.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the list to display without using a submit (meaning it appears when you click the checkbox) you need to use [Client-Side scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client-side_scripting) in a language such as Javascript, instead of PHP. PHP can only control the output that is sent to the client, once it is on the client being displayed in the browser you need a client-side language to make changes.

I highly recommend you use a library to do this as that will take care of a lot of stuff that you would otherwise need to do manually. If you would use [the very popular and widespread JQuery library](http://jquery.com/) your code could look like

```html
<html >
  <body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
 $("#list").hide();
 $("#ckeck").change(function() {  
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
   $("#list").show();
   $("#list2").hide();
    }
    else
    {
   $("#list").hide();
   $("#list2").show();
    }
   });
  });
  </script>
  <input type="checkbox" name="ckeck" id="ckeck">
  <select name="list" id="list" size="1">
 <option value="0">0</option>  
 <option value="1">1</option>
  </select>   
  <select name="list2" id="list2" size="1">
 <option value="12">12</option>  
 <option value="25">25</option>
  </select>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client-side_scripting#List_of_Client-Side_Scripting_Languages

Comment: If i use javascript can i send  the results to the my file, and using php get the result and using them?

Comment: @TLSK, no, you use javascript, for direct DOM modyfying

Answer (score 1):

Try using [.toogle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) like:

```js
$('#checkbox1').change(function() {
  $("select[name='list']").toggle(this.checked);
  $("select[name='list2']").toggle(!this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="check" id="checkbox1">

<select name="list" size="1" style="display:none">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
<select name="list2" size="1">
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="25">25</option>
</select>
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/mk02qmjh/1/